# Outputting raw image stream rather than jpeg, on-the-fly image resizing

Tags: php, html, image

I have a PHP function that does on-the-fly image resizing for thumbnail creation.

I am having trouble as it's just displaying raw image stream instead of the actual image.

My code is using a function called thumbnail:

```
$thumbnail = thumbnail($item['filename'], 209, 137);
imagejpeg($thumbnail);
```

I've tried putting in:

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

However, this just expects the full page to be an image. I have absolutely no idea where to go from here, been working at it for a while. I'd rather not save the image to disk although it's looking like this might be necessary.

Comment: This technique breaks the browser's ability to cache the image and can put a high load on the server.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without actually saving the image and still get it to display. I dont really mind about server load.

Comment: You need to set the header before you output the image.

Comment: I did, it still tries to view the whole page as an image.

Comment: I'm confused. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: outputting a jpeg image instead of the data stream from it, without saving the image to disc
currently its displaying like i opened the jpeg in a text editor.

Answer (score 15):

You either

### Do it [the normal way](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

This mean you point at *one* url, and serve the contents of *one* image:

```
<img src="myimage.php">
```

and `myimage.php` is a script that looks like:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($thumbnail);
die;
```

This technique has the advantage of being.. the normal way of doing things.

OR

### Output the image inline

Using [data uris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) outputting the contents as a [base64 encoded string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

This technique is most appropriate with small images.

It has the advantage of meaning all the images are in the main http request - at the (possibly sizable) disadvantage of making the page harder to edit/build and possibly negating the benefits of browser caching (unless the html page is itself cached).

### Being normal is easier

Regarding this statement in the question:

> However, this just expects the full page to be an image

That's right - if you do it the normal way you want to point at your php script with the `src` attribute of an image tag, and server *only* an image - i.e. the exact same response as if you were pointing at an image file with a browser.

Unless you have a good reason to do things a different way - the "normal" way is a good place to start.

Comment: the whole script is an include on a html page thats meant to display all the images.
Should i change it to have a script for image creation thats included in another script whose only purpose is to echo out images?

Comment: I don't understand your edited comment, if you want it to work you choose from the options presented above. Hint: data uris are not common

Comment: going to try the second one.
the current stream i get is from imagejpeg($thumbnail);
so trying:

    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . imagejpeg($thumbnail) .  '">';

Im pretty sure i went wrong somewhere here though

Comment: well... you'd need magic for that to work since the output for imagejpeg isn't base64 encoded (another hint google base64 encode and php). good luck

Comment: ahh would be great if code worked like magic, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can point an html img tag to an php file.

```
<img src='thumbnail.php?file=<?php echo $item['filename']; ?>' />
```

Then on your php file you display the image and change the headers since all it is doing is displaying an image.

```
$thumbnail = thumbnail($_GET['filename'], 209, 137);
imagejpeg($thumbnail);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
```

Comment: My html has:
<?php include 'scripts/images.php' ?>
that has the script in it, it goes through a small database of images and resizes as i go, i want it to be able to display them properly
this particular case only has 1 image in it

Comment: Yeah you don't want to use the php include function, you want to use a the html img tag so it treats each one independently.

Comment: It still has to have a php function going through each member of the database.

Comment: The idea is that instead of using image files as the `src` for your `img` tags in your HTML, you'll use a PHP file as the `src` that _only_ displays the single image you're interested in at that particular location, using something like GET parameters to determine which image to show a thumbnail of. So in this case you would have one HTML page which refers to a PHP script a lot of times, but using different parameters every time. And this PHP script would generate the image and output it as if it were a full page.

Comment: Correct Daan, your scripts/images.php file needs to echo html image tags not display the images. You can't do it all in one script. You need to separate getting multiple images from the database and displaying the images.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the image like you would a normal image in HTML and create the image in a separate PHP file:

***image.php***

```
<?php
$img = imagecreate(100,100); //Create an image 100px x 100px
imagecolorallocate($img, 255,0,0); //Fill the image red
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); //Set the content type to image/jpg
imagejpeg($img); //Output the iamge
imagedestroy($img); //Destroy the image
?>
```

***myWebpage.html***

```
<img src="image.php" />
```